# YouTube Data API fetch user's latest subscription

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch the latest subscriptions of a user. However, by defualt youtube is ordering them by relevance. If I am not wrong, the last time I checked youtube was returning them in latest order. Was it changed recently and is there any alternative way to have them ordered by latest without fetching all the subscriptions of a user. I am trying to optimize the quota limit usage.
If that's something impossible is there any way to fetch subscriptions of a particular day.

N.B: There's option to choose the ordering method, but none of option contains order by latest

I am using YouTube API's api interface to test the results. Passing the following values:
part: snippet
maxResults: 50
mine: True

available orders are: subscriptionOrderUnspecified, relevance (default), unread and alphabetical.
None of these order the result by latest subscription

[image]

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 1):

The default order for [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) is SUBSCRIPTION_ORDER_RELEVANCE so unless you are setting the order i would expect it to return by relevance

[image]

Comment: My goal is to fetch someone's latest subscription list. Found none of the given order does that

Comment: Well if you check the documentation you will notice that you can't sort by date

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the subscription list of a certain date somehow

Comment: The image is the order that you can set it there is no way to order by date

Answer (score 0):

> If I am not wrong, the last time I checked youtube was returning them in latest order.

If by *latest order* you mean getting first the most recent subscriber then `myRecentSubscribers` filter in [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) seems to solve your problem.